# How to get a list of roles with certain permission in Spatie/permission (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, permissions, acl, laravel-permission

I am trying to get it by same way i am getting the list of users with a certain Permission, but with role it's not working throwing me

> Call to undefined method Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::roles()

The way i get list of users with a certain role:

```
$permission = $request->permission;
$usersWithPerms = User::permission($permission)->get(); 
return array("usersWithPerms"=>$usersWithPerms);
```

The way im trying to get roles with a certain permission:

```
  $groupsWithPerms = Role::permission('perms_givePermToRole')->get(); 
  return array("groupsWithPerms"=>$groupsWithPerms);
```

> BadMethodCallException
>       Call to undefined method Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::roles()

Comment: i think your question is wrong 

because every role has many permissions not the opposite

Comment: no, it's not wrong, cause there are many roles with same perm, so i want a list of roles that have assigned some perm. But i got it work. Ty

Answer (score 2):

**get the permissions of a role**
and **get the roles of a permission**

```
$permission = Permission::findOrFail(1);
$groupsWithPerms = $permission->getRoleNames();
//dd($groupsWithPerms);

$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
$groupsWithRoles = $role->getPermissionNames();
//dd($groupsWithRoles);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i get its a name but not id of the roles with a certain permission:

```
$permission = Permission::findOrFail($request->idPermission);
$groupsWithPerms = $permission->getRoleNames();
```

Where: getRoleNames() is a method from spatie package.
So this works fine but you only get the names of the roles not ids.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built shortcut to get them in the package, but querying for them is simple enough:

```php
//Eager load roles to get all data in just 1 query
$permission = Permission::with('roles')
    ->where('name', 'perms_givePermToRole')
    ->first();
$rolesWithPerm = $permission->roles;

//or

$rolesWithPerm = Role::whereHas('permissions', function($permissions){
   $permissions->where('name', 'perms_givePermToRole');
})->get();
```